# How to calculate how far an object travels given the launch angle

Tags: javascript, math, formula, equation

I would like to be able to calculate how far something travels given the launch angle (assuming a constant force). I know already that launching an object at 45 degrees gives it the longest distance (let's call this distance "1") and that launching the same object at 60 degrees gives it distance 1/2.
However, I do not want the calculation to just be that. I want something for the whole entire 88 degrees (1-89). I don't want an array filled with numbers, I want an *equation*. And oh, this is in JavaScript, but that shouldn't really matter because this is an equation.

Comment: [Projectile motion formulas](http://formulas.tutorvista.com/physics/projectile-motion-formula.html)

Comment: Math.[function] for the trig functions

Comment: but lookout because the built in formulas are probably in radians

Comment: Time to learn some elementary physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a = 45;

d = Math.sin(2*a*Math.PI/180);

60 won't go .5 it will go .866.

Comment: Split the force into vertical and horizontal components and then calculate the time of flight using vertical component and distance=horizontal*time of flight.